# How to add the looped value inside string.match?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops

How to loop through a string and add its value inside of regex in the match method. I'm getting null.
Tried with  `/'str[i]'/g` and it also gives null.

```
var str = "helloWorld";
var regResult;

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  regResult = str.match(/str[i]/g); //gives null
};
```

Comment: [javascript - How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your regular expression is matching `str` followed by a single character from the range `i` - one single `i`, meaning it will match `stri`. To match the variable `i`, try the following:

```
var str = "helloWorld";
var regResult;

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  regResult = str.match(new RegExp('str' + i, 'g')); //gives null
};
```

Here we are creating a regular expression whose pattern contains the current value of the variable `i`. As an example, if `i` is 4 then the regular expression will be constructed as if you had simply given `/str4/g` to `str.match`.

## EDIT

To reflect the edit made to the question, my new proposed solution is as follows:

```
var str = "helloWorld";
var regResult;

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  regResult = str.match(new RegExp(str[i], 'g')); //gives null
};
```

This code differs from the above code in that it is reading the value `i` from `str`. For example if `i` is 4 and `str[4] = "h"`, then the regular expression will be constructed as if you had simply given the value of `str[4]` to `str.match`: `str.match(/h/g)`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the change to the question @Deke

Comment: But this will insert only `['d']` in the `regResult` array, from the last iteration, it needs to be adjusted. and also what's `ars`?

Comment: I'm not actually sure where `ars` came from @cнŝdk. I was probably typing when I was tired (again). It's been fixed now

Comment: Wait, nevermind. `ars` was the original name of the variable in the question, before it was edited. I must have missed the name change.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need just a little bit fix

```
var str = "helloWorld";
var regResult;

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    regResult = str.match(new RegExp(str[i], 'g'));
    console.log(regResult)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// static RegExp -> /str[i]/g is just equal "str[i]"
// dynamic RegExp -> new RegExp(str[i], "g") is str[i] h,e,l,l, ...

var str = "helloWorld";
var regResult;

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  regResult = str.match(new RegExp(str[i], "g")); //gives null
  console.log(regResult);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **[`new RegExp()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)**, so you can dynamically create the regex with the iterated `string`:

```
str.match(new RegExp(str[i],'g'))
```

But if you are trying to get an `array` of matches for every letter in the `string` you need to `push` the `matches` array in your `regResult` and not just keep overrding its value on every iteration:

```
regResult.push(str.match(new RegExp(str[i], 'g'))); //gives null
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "helloWorld";
var regResult = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  regResult.push(str.match(new RegExp(str[i], 'g'))); //gives null
};
console.log(regResult);
```